# Unknown glitch in batch

Tags: batch-file, debugging

I need help with an unknown issue in a recent batch file executed on Windows 10.

Proper function:
I am trying to make a math quiz which generates two numbers, a basic operand (`+-x/`), finds the answer, then checks it against an answer from a user. Additionally, the program is made to track certain information after a user has put in their answer. (Question number, the problem and answer, and the users response.)

My issue:
In certain scenarios the program will display the problem/answer in the "game" window rather than writing the problem/answer in the text file as intended.

The command is:

```
echo [Q]%m%>>"C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\%fname%.txt"
```

It is comment marked in the code below.

What I've done to fix the issue?
After testing for a descent while I discovered the issue seemed to revolve around the portion where it tries to move a problem/answer combo with division as the operation. This helped, but the issue started randomly popping up throughout future attempts to debug.

While I feel it is a bit frowned upon to ask two things at once I have two more issues.

1. Why does an operation like `%a%%b%%c%=%d%` (`a`,`c`,`d` being numbers and `b` being a `/`) break a certain command in my code consistently and how can I fix it?
2. Why does the same issue still randomly appear even if I erase all traces of division `/` which seems to cause my issue in the first place.

Here is the batch file:

```
::Initialization
@echo off
set /a prb=3
set file=Stat
set sss=s.
if %prb%==1 set tst=.
echo.
echo Welcome to math fire, you will get randomly generated 
echo multiplication, addition, and subtraction problems. You 
echo will go through a specified number before the game ends 
echo and this window closes. You will be tracked in a file on 
echo your desktop. You will have %prb% problem%sss%
echo.
pause
CLS
echo Get ready
timeout 5
set start=%time%
CLS
set /a num=1
set /a good=0
set /a bad=0
::===========================Set up beggining of stat file.
echo =-=-=-=-=-=>>"C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\%fname%.txt"
echo ===Start===>>"C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\%fname%.txt"
echo =-=-=-=-=-=>>"C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\%fname%.txt"
echo.>>"C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\%fname%.txt"
::===================================Main Body============
::[A] Num1 [B] Operator [C] Num2 [D] Answer [E] The problem [M] Problem and answer
:main
set /a a=%random% %% 30 + 1 

::To remove the division section I changed the 4 below to 3
set /a b=%random% %% 4 + 1

set /a c=%random% %% 20 + 1 
if %b%==1 set b=+
if %b%==2 set b=-
if %b%==3 set b=*
if %b%==4 set b=/
set /a d=%a%%b%%c%
set e=%a%%b%%c%
echo.
echo =============================%e%=?
echo.
timeout 1
set /p ans=+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++Answer:
set m=%e%=%d%
echo ===%num%===>>"C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\%fname%.txt"

::The following line is the glitching code
echo [Q]%m%>>"C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\%fname%.txt"  

echo [A]%ans%>>"C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\%fname%.txt"
echo.>>"C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\%fname%.txt"
if %ans%==%d% goto p
CLS
echo.
echo -----------------------------Incorrect
set /a bad=%bad%+1
goto re
:p
CLS
echo.
echo -----------------------------Correct
set /a good=%good%+1
goto re
:re
if %num%==%prb% goto end
set /a num=%num%+1
goto main
:end
echo ===========>>"C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\%fname%.txt"
echo.>>"C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\%fname%.txt"
echo [Start]%start%>>"C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\%fname%.txt"
echo [-End-]%time%>>"C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\%fname%.txt"
echo [Right]%good%>>"C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\%fname%.txt"
echo [Wrong]%bad%>>"C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\%fname%.txt"
echo.>>"C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\%fname%.txt"
echo =-=-=-=-=-=>>"C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\%fname%.txt"
echo ===-End-===>>"C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\%fname%.txt"
echo =-=-=-=-=-=>>"C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\%fname%.txt"
echo.>>"C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\%fname%.txt"
CLS
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo Congrats, check your desktop for your play info.
echo.
echo.
echo.
pause 
exit
```

Comment: Two hints: First, it is better to use `%UserProfile%` instead of `C:\Users\%username%` as the user's profile directory can be on any drive with any path, see [Windows Environment Variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows). Second, read DosTips forum topic [ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ECHO/](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774) and better use `echo/` instead of `echo.` in your batch file  for blank lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the syntax

```
>>"%filename1%"  echo [Q]%m%
```

(my testfiles are allotted in variables)

Noting that `m` will contain a string such as `13/14=0`

The character just before a redirector redirects the logical device number. You can get around this by moving the redirction to the start of the command or inserting a space before the redirector or using

```
>>"%filename1%"  (
 echo [Q]%m%
 echo something else
 echo more text
)
```

or

```
(
 echo [Q]%m%
 echo something else
 echo more text
)>>"%filename1%"
```

which does the same thing - gather the output of the `echo`es and redirect the sum-output to the file.

Oh, BTW - batch does integer mathematics, so 13/4=3 - no decimals.

Comment: Thank you, just plugged everything in and everything seems to be working. (Kinda wish I knew why this was bugging out in the first place though...)

Comment: Since `m` contains that ends with a digit and that is directly before a redirector (`>`) then `cmd` decides to redirect the logical device #. Logical device 0 is stdin (normally keyboard), 1 is stdout (console), 2 is stderr (also console, for error reports) and 3..9 undefined (but can be assigned - I've seen tem used once) Hence the last digit disappears since `cmd` uses it as part of the redirection command. Now attempting to redirect stdin as an output for instance is very likely to fail... Cure: move the redirection, make the character before the redirector a non-digit or (combine output)

Comment: Ok now I see what you meant earlier, thank you, you've been a big help